# GWT RPC "404 not found" error. How do you get RPC to work on your own Apache server?

Tags: gwt, rpc

The RPC I implemented works fine in dev mode. But as soon as I copy the code into a real apache server the RPC stops working! **How do you configure your GWT application so that the RPC will work on the apache server?** I have found the GWT tutorial on RPC but it is not very helpful. **Other links about RPC configuration would be very much appreciated!**

---

I developed some GWT code. I implemented and got working an RPC client-server communication. When I say it is working... I mean that it works great in development mode. I can click and it interacts with the server as expected.

Then when I do a GWT compile and copy the war directory into my apache server htdocs folder. I can view the website but when I click on the button that is supposed to initiate an RPC nothing happens. I check the Firefox-->tools-->web console and see "NAMEOFRPC 404 not found".

Here is my WEB-INF web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>NameOfRpc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.nameOfModule.server.rpc.NameOfRpcImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NameOfRpc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/nameOfModule</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>NameOfModule.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is the firefox web-console error I get:

```
[16:50:58.792] POST http://SERVER/gwt/nameOfModule/nameOfModule/NameOfRpc [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 3065ms]
```

I copy the war folder into /SERVER/gwt and then rename it to nameOfModule.

**Is there anything wrong with my WEB-INF/web.xml?**

Comment: What is in your @RemoteServiceRelativePath on you com.company.nameOfModule.server.rpc.NameOfRpc interface?

Comment: The java code NameOfRpc.java is: @RemoteServiceRelativePath("RpcGetXml").

Comment: When I change the @ RemoteServiceRelativePath I get a new "404 not found" that corresponds to whatever I have put into the @ RemoteServiceRelativePath field. EX: changed it to "TESTING". Then I got a new 404 not found http://SERVER/gwt/nameOfModule/nameOfModule/TESTING .

Comment: do you have tomcat running? Any JVM actually hosting the webapp?

Comment: the server side endpoint has to be a JVM Contianer capable of hosting regular J2EE servlets.

Comment: @Zasz, We have a wiki running using apache. So far I have just been using the apache htdocs folder to serve my gwt page. If I understand correctly, I need to get tomcat and start using tomcat to serve my gwt application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is some running JVM instance, running a J2EE servlet container, which is hosting your servlet code. Apache, as I understand is simply a http server, and does not run java code, or host servlets, out of the box. I'm assuming your wiki is simply a clump of HTML pages served by apache.

Tomcat is merely an option. It is the standard JVM contatiner folks use for hosting java servlets. It is also capable of serving HTML files, so you can stop using apache http server if you use tomcat.

Your app worked well in development mode, because GWT Hosted Mode has in-built Jetty server, which is a lightweight servlet container comparable to tomcat. Servers like tomcat and jetty and jboss are the ones which actually read your web.xml and do what you have described in it.

Comment: I got tomcat. Configured and ran the server on my dev machine. I then copied the GWT war folder onto the tomcat webapss folder. Then i was able to successfully run my GWT application and it worked exactly like in dev mode.

Comment: If I were to summarize your verbose answer it would basically say: your apache server can not run servlets that is why your GWT application doesn't work. You need to load your GWT application onto a server that can run servlets. One example server that can run servlets is Tomcat.

Comment: stackoverflow is a good way to learn how to write technically IMO and how to write persuasively. both are very important skills. (one of the creators of stackoverflow also thinks the same way: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/02/how-to-write-without-writing.html)

Comment: are you developing on windows/linux/mac ? do you use tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want the following in your web.xml:

```
<url-pattern>/nameOfModule/RpcGetXml</url-pattern>
```

Or whatever is in your RemoteServiceRelativePath